# how can I Send File via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, file-upload, form-data

I want send a file via JQuery

I create a form like this:

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text">
<input type="file">
</form>
```

and I use this Jquery code to send data.

```
    var datastring = $("#form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "function/formRegister",
        data: datastring,
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
        }
```

I can send input.text value to server But I can not send input.file

I know I must FormData. how can I use it?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/8303694

Comment: please try searching before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `serialize` try `FormData`

```
var datastring = new FormData($("#form")[0]);
```

Add this in your ajax to tell dont worry about content & dont process data

```
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false
```